# Diagnose battery drain in small appliance

Tags: batteries, discharge

Novice here, wondering of any "low hanging fruits", very simple initial checks that one can do to find out why a small, AA/AAA battery-operated appliance is draining them faster than it's supposed to.

Case in point, an automated cat flap operated by 4 AA batteries is discharging them in 2-3 days where originally it took many weeks into months. I tried new, quality batteries, now rechargeable ones - same result.

There are no external signs of damage, leaks, rust, oxidation, etc. There is also no sign that something mechanical (like the flap lock opening) is continually happening, that would be quite obvious.

Comment: +1 for enlighting me that there are automatic cat flaps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short story**

Clean the optical reflector and/or remove cat hairs from the tunnel around the optical sense head.

**Long-story**

My cat flap has an IR diode and reflector back to a sensor. This is pulsed at a low duty cycle and thus maintains very low battery consumption. When a relatively slow moving object like a cat enters the "tunnel", the low power beam is broken and the magnetic field is activated. That magnetic field can sense the "chip" that the cat carries under its skin.

The data from the chip is read by the cat-flap's electronics and, if the data matches pre-stored data for one of my several cats, the flap solenoid is energized and the cat can push on the flap to open it and enter the house.

If the optical sensor gets blocked, the magnetic field is permanently energized and this kills the batteries in days so, try cleaning the optical reflection system.

Comment: That makes sense, I'm going to try it and report back.